# VB Custom login page. Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Tags: sql, vb.net, authentication

I am creating a custom log in page using VB in Visual Studio. Every time I try logging in, however, I get the following error:
"Incorrect syntax near '.'".
When I put in the wrong username/password combo it recognizes this, but when it is right it will get this error and fail to log in.

```
        Private Function VerifyLogin(ByVal UserName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim cnn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        cnn.ConnectionString = My.MySettings.Default.RedwoodConnectionString.Replace(";Integrated Security=True", ";Integrated Security=False") & UserSetting
        Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (principal_id) FROM _ sys.database_principals WHERE(name = '" & UserName & "')"
        cnn.Open()
        Dim i As Integer
        i = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        cnn.Close()
        If (i > 0) Then Return True
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message & vbNewLine & "Location: VerifyLogin() in Login.vb" & vbNewLine & "Returned value: False")
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You database query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this portion of your sql:

> FROM _ sys.database_principals

See the mistake there? It thinks the `_` is the full table name and `sys` is an alias. At this point, `.database_principals` is no longer valid, hence your error.

And while we're at it, *you really need to fix the sql injection vulnerability!!*

Comment: Wow thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that. Guess we all have those moments sometimes!
This is an in-class exercise for a database class and we have not learned what sql injection vulnerability is yet :P. I will have to read into it, but this is for a fake company so there's no real data at risk at least :)
Thanks again!